# Unable to add and remove menu option from fragment and navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I am getting an issue of hiding and adding the menu item in fragment and navigation drawer as I in my application I have logout and adding contact menu and I want to set logout option in all but don't need an adding contact button in all screen. As my application contains four view pager tab fragment and navigation drawer. I have added my menu through menu XML file. 
And I want my logout option in all fragment in navigation drawer but adding contact in only on my first tab fragment.

Here is code of Main  Activity:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
val menuInflater = menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
val menuLogout = menu.findItem(R.id.logout)
val menuadd = menu.findItem(R.id.iadd_contact)

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: android.view.MenuItem): Boolean {
when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.logout -> {

                postLogout(path, params) { response ->
                }
            }


        return true

    R.id.iadd_contact -> {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE)

        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    }
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

What is going with that when I move from fragment A to Fragment B i want only logout button enable and add contact disable and then when I again go revert back from Fragment B to Fragment A my add contact menu also get disable but that I want to be in Fragment A only and same as it happens when I open my navigation drawer

And in fragment I have set my code like this:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)

menu!!.removeItem(R.id.iadd_contact)
}
```

and it oncreateview:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
setHasOptionsMenu(false)
rootv = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.edit_profile, container, false)
activity.invalidateOptionsMenu()
return rootv
}
```

Simply I just want my  `R.id.iadd_contact` in my first tab fragment to enable and in all other fragment disable so due to fragment back stack or moving again from another fragment to my first tab fragment my add  `R.id.iadd_contact` get also removed.

Answer (score 0):

first override onCreate Method

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }
```

And then inflate menu in your fragment

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        menu!!.clear()
        inflater!!.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    }
```

Comment: remove onCreateOptionsMenu from MainActivity and add into fragment.. create separate menu files

Comment: This work fine with simple viewpager tab fragment. I have created separete onCreateOptionsmenu in fragment. But now problem i m getting with Navigation Drawer fragment files. When i come from navigation drawer fragment files back to my tab fragment then there visibilty also gone. How do i handle with Navigation drawer fragment files too also.

Comment: try with separete onCreateOptionsmenu  for navigation fragment

Comment: I have created separate menu also for navigation drawer but its not working

Comment: have you added onCreate in navigation fragment ?

Comment: yes, i have created OnCreate in fragment and then set sethasoptionmenu(true)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153240/discussion-between-pavya-and-megha-parmar).